# Auto-rebuild RAID6 with MDADM

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, opensuse-11.3

I have an openSUSE 11.3 Linux computer with 5 disks of 1TB (WD enterprise disks) in it. With `mdadm` I configured a RAID6 device.

Now, after a lot of thorough testing, I've noticed that when the computer goes down unsuspectedly it could happen (1 time out of 10) that while booting, the `md0` device isn't recognised, and then the machine goes in "recovery mode", which means that I have to 'CTRL+C' it so it can boot to openSUSE. Once in openSUSE I have to re-add the drive manually with `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdX`. After this everything works back fine (after resynching).

So my question is: Is there a way to auto-rebuild the RAID6 device when there are problems?
And how can I stop this "recovery mode" from happening. Because the computer will be in a place I can't go to, to connect a keyboard, 'CTRL+C' it just to get in openSUSE.

My files:

```
cat /etc/mdadm.conf

DEVICE containers partitions
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=d300b3c5:553c4f26:ce909d5a:0f456417
```

```
cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid6 sdb1[0] sdf1[5] sde1[3] sdd1[2] sdc1[1]
   2930281728 blocks super 1.0 level 6, 128k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]
   bitmap: 0/466 pages [0KB], 1024KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

```
cat /etc/fstab

/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3500418AS_9VM6LN3Y-part1 swap                 swap       defaults              0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3500418AS_9VM6LN3Y-part2 /                    ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 1
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3500418AS_9VM6LN3Y-part3 /home                ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 2
proc                 /proc                proc       defaults              0 0
sysfs                /sys                 sysfs      noauto                0 0
debugfs              /sys/kernel/debug    debugfs    noauto                0 0
usbfs                /proc/bus/usb        usbfs      noauto                0 0
devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-d300b3c5:553c4f26:ce909d5a:0f456417 /home/mobotix        ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 2
```

Comment: are you using a /etc/mdadm.conf file, and is md0 showing "persistant superblock" (cat /proc/md0)

Comment: Try posting those files here (inside a code block) as well as the content of /etc/fstab

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Note that we're NOT a forum! Next time please edit your question (using the same user: http://superuser.com/users/65632/user65632), rather than adding "answers". Success!

Comment: The thing is that I already have an mdadm.conf!!!
if I make a /etc/mdadm.conf with that command, that won't change a thing!

why??

==> assume that my server boots with a broken RAID (Drive 3 'broken')
first of all, my server will go into recovery mode (NO netwerk enabled) so i have to go to my server and ctrl+c it!
and if i put the command you say, it will make a /etc/mdadm.conf with all the disks EXCEPT drive 3. because it has failed according to the server (which it didn't!!)


correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new mdadm.conf file:

```
$su

#mdadm --detail --scan --verbose > /etc/mdadm.conf
```

And you're done.

Comment: The author of the question does not understand how this will help him, and for some reason he cannot add comments himself. Can you please explain what this will do ?

Comment: yep.. almost OS automatically scans and activates the disk arrays.And because the system doesn't automatically create a file to remember components/partitions of the RAID set, so we just help it.

Comment: The thing is that I already have an `mdadm.conf`! if I make a `/etc/mdadm.conf` with that command, that won't change a thing! why? ==> assume that my server boots with a broken RAID (Drive 3 'broken') first of all, my server will go into recovery mode (NO netwerk enabled) so i have to go to my server and ctrl+c it! and if i put the command you say, it will make a `/etc/mdadm.conf` with all the disks EXCEPT drive 3. because it has failed according to the server (which it didn't!!) correct me if I'm wrong!